# Linking Framework in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: frameworks, compilation, linker, xcode5, keyboard-events

I'm trying to add existing Application Services framework in my program in Xcode 5.0.2, however, I get the following error when executing "make" in terminal to compile.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent", referenced from:
      _main in main-gNfV8b.o
  "_CGEventPost", referenced from:
      _main in main-gNfV8b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I added the application framework to my project using "Add Files," and I've included the correct header file. What am I doing incorrectly?

Here are the important snippets of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
     CGEventRef plus_on, plus_off;

     plus_on = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)31, true);
     plus_off = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)31, false);

     CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, plus_on);

     CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, plus_off);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update - I'm still having trouble linking/compiling in terminal, but it runs successfully in Xcode. Not sure why.